# Guava Import Issue

Tags: java, guava

I store Guava Library and a testing file **Test.java** in **C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\bin** and execute following commands in command prompt:

[image]

When I remove the import commands from my code, program execute properly (last command). Can anybody help me where is the problem because it is showing errors with imports.

My code is following:

```
import com.google.common.collect.HashMultimap;
import com.google.common.collect.Multimap;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String key = "hello";
            Multimap myMap = HashMultimap.create();
            myMap.put(key, 1);
            myMap.put(key, 5000);
            System.out.println(myMap.get(key));
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're missing a period in `guava-11.0.2.jar`.  Your console appears to indicate that you're typing `guava-11.0.2jar`, without a period between the `2` and the `jar`.

Comment: Sorry. But problem remains same.

Comment: Are you sure you're giving it the class path correctly?  You might try giving it the full path, starting from `C:\`.

Comment: I'm talking about the command line -- just do something like `javac -cp guava-11.0.2.jar Test.java`.

Comment: Thanks. Can you kindly help me by providing what command should I use for compilation and running.

Comment: Because **javac -cp guava-11.0.2.jar Test.java** it works. But after that **java Test** not working

Comment: You may need to specify `java -cp guava-11.0.2.jar Test`.

Comment: That is, you need to add Guava to the classpath both for javac _and_ for java.

Comment: Did you make it work?  I suspect, in retrospect, you might need something like `java -cp "guava-11.0.2.jar;Test.class" Test...I dunno.  Almost nobody deals with this directly because they all use an IDE that does it for them.

Answer (score 2):

You are passing a relative path to '-cp', but you are already in the right directory. Either pass the full path 'c:\Program files...' or the relative path, which **depends** on where you currently are in your filesystem. In the case you show in your screenshot

```
javac -cp guava-11.0.2.jar Test.java
```

should do.

Comment: Thanks. **javac -cp guava-11.0.2.jar Test.java** it works. But after that **java Test** not working (2nd image).

Comment: Same thing. The java command also needs the classpath. And if this answers your question, please accept the answer.